# reload component - React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

how to make component to reload , what I mean not re-render the component but I want to make `componentDidMount` to be called again (re-start **life cycle** of component)

```
class Test extends Component 
{

    componentDidMount()
    {
        console.log('component did mount');
    }

    reload = () => 
    {
        //RELOAD COMPONENT
    };

    render()
    {
        return (<Button onPress={this.reload}/>)
    }

}
```

Comment: The only way that's possible is by unmounting the component and then rendering it all over again. Have a look at this: https://tylermcginnis.com/an-introduction-to-life-cycle-events-in-react-js/

Comment: I don't think it'll be a good idea to unmount a component. I'd rather ask you to use `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method for doing anything you're doing in `componetDidMount`

Comment: Could you please post your root problem? I think more people can help you, because what you want to do should not be done. I think we can help you better when you post your root problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can call the life-cycle methods explicitly

```
reload = () => 
{
    //RELOAD COMPONENT
    this.componentDidMount();
};
```

If you want to re-start the life-cycle, you have to remove it from the DOM and re-add it.

Answer (score 4):

What you want can be done. But it is not the best practice. Basically, you need to toggle the availability of your component from the parent component. As shown below, parent component has a state property to tract the availability of the child component.

```js
class Parent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      showChild : true
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      console.log('Parent Mounted');
  }

  reloadChild = () => {
      this.setState({
        showChild : false
      })
    
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          showChild : true
        })
      },100);

      console.log("Reload Child Invoked")
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div >
        {this.state.showChild?
          <Child reloadChild={this.reloadChild}/> : null
        }
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

The Child component would look as below

```js
class Child extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('Child component Mounted');
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    console.log('Child Component Unmounted');
  }

  onButtonClick = () => {
    console.log("Button Clicked")
    this.props.reloadChild();
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>
        Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }

}
```

When you click on the button of the child component, it will call the method in parent Component which toggle the availability of the child component. Note that I've used setInterval in the reloadChild() method to toggle the availability. As I've said earlier, this is not the best practice. Just a workaround.

Comment: that may works but not what i was hoping for , thanks any way

Comment: I think you meant to use setTimeout instead of setInterval. Looks like you are triggering componentDidMount by first removing it from the DOM and then re-add it.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the answer. Only way to re-start the component lifecycle is by removing and then adding it back to the DOM as per OP's requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Each time a component is created and destroyed, place this in the global variable componentArray so that all life cycle methods under this can be called externally.

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    // add 
    window.componentArray = window.componentArray || []
    this.index = new Date().getTime()
    window.componentArray.push(this)
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    console.log('componentDidMount')
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    // remove
    window.componentArray = window.componentArray || []
    window.componentArray = window.componentArray.reduce((pre,obj)=>{
      if(this.index != obj.index){
        pre.push(obj)
      }
      return pre
    },[])
  }
  reComponentDidMount(){
    this.componentDidMount()
  }
  render(){
    return <div>test</div>
  }
}


// outside like this run
componentArray.forEach(o=>{
   o.componentDidMount()
})
```

Comment: Can you please add explanation also?